# Lonely \item - perhaps a missing list environment

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, moderncv, splitbib

My problem is:

I am using `moderncv` and `splitbib` on a mac. In Linux my file compiles fine. In the mac, however, i run `pdflatex` and `bibtex` all right, but when I run `pdflatex` again, I get the error

> Lonely \item - perhaps a missing list environment

Here's a MWE. The first section is kind of standard for `moderncv`, then I use `splitbib` to produce bibliography in several sections. Then there are two CV sections with an entry for the sake of completeness only and lastly, my linking to the bib file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

\firstname{MyName}
\familyname{MyLastName}

% SPLITBIB
\usepackage[export]{splitbib} % So I can display publications by categories.
\begin{category}{\subsection{Press}}
\SBentries{press1}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{\subsection{Presentations}}
 \SBentries{pres1,pres2}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{\subsection{Papers}}
 \SBentries{paper1,paper2}
\end{category}

% BEGIN DOC
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2005--2010}{Deg}{Some U}{Someplace}{Computer Science}{Some notes}

\subsection{Professional}
\cventry{2000--2005}{Technical Specialist}{Some company}{Some City}{}{Some description} 

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} % change the symbol for lists

\nocite{*}

%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\SBtitlestyle{simple}
%\SBsubtitlestyle{none}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}     % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

For completeness, if someone wants to try it, here's the sample publications.bib used with this MWE.

```
@UNPUBLISHED{pres1,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {Some title},
  note = {Presentation at XYZ},
  month = {July.},
  year = {2010}
  }

@UNPUBLISHED{pres2,
  author = {First Guy and Second Guy},
  title = {Some title},
  note = {Presentation at some University},
  month = {Nov.},
  year = {2008}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAPERS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@inproceedings{paper1,
    author = {Author One and Author Two},
    booktitle = {Anyone can get a Book},
    posted-at = {2010-07-23 15:33:06},
    publisher = {Springer},
    editor = {John Doe and Juan Perez},
    title = {Some Catchy Title},
    year = {2012}
}
@inproceedings{paper2,
  author    = {Author one and Author two},
  title     = {Complicated Title},
  booktitle = {pretentious journal},
  year      = {2011},
  pages     = {568-577}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Press
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %author    = {Phil McKenna},
@misc{press1,
  month     = {March},
  author   = {{New Scientist}},
  title     = {What you thought true is no more},
  howpublished = {\url{http://bit.ly/be0PpB}},
  year      = {2010}
}
```

Comment: When the same file is compiled on one machine, but not on the other, I would suppose different file versions of packages or executables – or missing ones. Add `\listfiles` at the very beginning of your MWE, and run this once in Linux, once in MacOS. Compare afterwards the file list found at the end of the produced log files.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation

> Since [`splitbib`] deeply redefines `\bibitem` and `thebibliography` environment, it must be loaded after packages that redefine those commands...

However the `moderncv` class, version 2013/02/09 v1.3.0, does redefine exactly those commands.  On the other hand, `moderncv` sets up things so that `multibib` works.  You can use this to get subdivided bibliographies with your `bib` file as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\firstname{MyName}
\familyname{MyLastName}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{press}{Press}
\newcites{presentations}{Presentations}
\newcites{papers}{Papers}

% BEGIN DOC
\begin{document}
\nocitepress{press1}
\nocitepresentations{pres1,pres2}
\nocitepapers{paper1,paper2}

\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2005--2010}{Deg}{Some U}{Someplace}{Computer Science}{Some notes}

\subsection{Professional}
\cventry{2000--2005}{Technical Specialist}{Some company}{Some City}{}{Some description} 

\section{Publications}

\bibliographystylepress{plain}
\bibliographypress{publications} 

\bibliographystylepresentations{plain}
\bibliographypresentations{publications} 

\bibliographystylepapers{plain}
\bibliographypapers{publications} 

\end{document}
```

compiled via

```
pdflatex file
bibtex press
bibtex presentations
bibtex papers
pdflatex file
pdflatex file
```