# bibentry with template causes error: lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment

Tags: bibentry

I am using this template  http://www.latextemplates.com/template/cies-resume-cv to create a cv and a bib file to keep all publications etc.

I am trying to use nobibliography to be able to do this without adding a reference list at the end of the document, however this leads to the error

> lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment

after each bibentry.  I expect there's something in structure that is interfering with nobibliography - as if I remove that line then the error goes away.  I also have no error if I replace \nobibliography with \bibliography.  I have tried adding the package before and after the structure to see if this made a difference (it doesn't).

I have looked at these solutions   [Lonely item error in bibliography .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316287/lonely-item-error-in-bibliography-bbl-file)

[Lonely \item - perhaps a missing list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101397/lonely-item-perhaps-a-missing-list-environment)
and a few others but no luck

Is there a way to fix this problem? or an alternative to nobibliography that will achieve the same outcome?  Being able to have a separate bib file and enter the full citation in the text, no list at the end.

**Here is an MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\include{structure} % Include structure.tex which contains packages and document layout definitions

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document} 

\hspace{2pt} \textbf{Journal Articles}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \bibentry{bib1}
 \item \bibentry{bib2}
\end{itemize}


 % bibliography info
 \bibliographystyle{plain} %plain is my normal one
\nobibliography{bibexample}

\end{document}
```

with example bib file

```
@article{bib1,
author  = "George D. Greenwade",
title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year    = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume  = "14",
number  = "3",
pages   = "342--351"
}


 @book{bib2,
 author    = {Peter Babington}, 
 title     = {The title of the work},
 publisher = {The name of the publisher},
 year      = 1993,
 volume    = 4,
 series    = 10,
 address   = {The address},
 edition   = 3,
 month     = 7,
 note      = {An optional note},
 isbn      = {3257227892}
 }
```

Comment: The reported error or any other error did not happen in my computer.

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone else encounters this problem - it is a clash between the hyperref and bibentry packages.  The solution, from [Clash between bibentry and hyperref with bibstyle elsart-harv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/clash-between-bibentry-and-hyperref-with-bibstyle-elsart-harv) is to use

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother
```

In my case this needed to be changed in structure.tex, the template I was using.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with my CV. Thanks for your solution, it saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thank you so much, same issue happened to me and your solution was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had the same issue and this resolved it.

Comment: This fixes the error. But \bibentry{referenceLabel} also produces nothing so bibentry does not seem to be functional.

Comment: I posted my problem as a question with a minimal example that shows that it is not working: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679860/full-in-text-citation-without-biblatex

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution given by Esme_ worked but broke all the references links of my document. In order to use bibentry + having a references list you need to use the package `natbib` at some point, please check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81937/hyperref-bibentry-natbib-conflict-incorrect-hyperlink) for more details.